# Searching any item in a list from another list using Java Streams

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have 2 List list:

```
//Dynamic lists - sent in request
List<String> types = {"VCX", "ATCH", "Warrnty"};

//hardcoded eligble list in code
List<String> eligibleTypes = {"VCX", "ATCH", "Warrnty"};
```

Now I want to return true if any of the entries in **types** list is present in hardcoded **eligibleTypes** list? How can I write a clean code using Java streams?

```java
boolean isAnyChildEligible = types.stream()
    .anyMatch(type -> isEligibleProgram(type, eligibleTypes));

private boolean isEligibleProgram(String type, List<String> eligibleTypes) {
    if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(eligibleTypes) && eligibleTypes.contains(type)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Any better way of doing the above? Using some other method? Will the above even work?

Comment: which `CollectionUtils` you use here `!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(eligibleTypes)`?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Collections method like below

```
Collections.disjoint(types, eligibleTypes)
```

returns true if no common element between list.

Hope this helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `eligibleTypes` can never be null, you can write this without the `isEligibleProgram()` method:

```
boolean isAnyChildEligible = types.stream().anyMatch(eligibleTypes::contains);
```